# Where is the missing parenthesis?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to learn SQL Databases, but I cannot seem to understand where the problem here is, I keep getting told that there is a missing right parenthesis. Would appreciate if someone could point out where the issue is (I'm working on Oracle 11G XE):

```
create table emp_copy
employee_id NUMBER(6)
CONSTRAINT emp_employee_id PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR2(20)
, last_name VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT emp_lname_nn NOT NULL
, email VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT emp_mail NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT emp_mail_uk UNIQUE
, phone_number VARCHAR2(20)
, hire_date DATE default sysdate
CONSTRAINT emp_hire_date NOT NULL
, job_id VARCHAR2(10)
CONSTRAINT emp_job NOT NULL
, salary NUMBER(8,2)
CONSTRAINT emp_sal_ck CHECK (salary>0)
, commission_pct NUMBER(2,2)
, mgr_id NUMBER(6)
CONSTRAINT emp_mgr_fk REFERENCES
employees (employee_id)
, department_id NUMBER(4)
CONSTRAINT empdept_fk REFERENCES
dept (deptno) [ON DELETE CASCADE | ON DELETE SET NULL] );
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. For example, you don't have parenthesis around the column/constraint definitions and that `[ON DELETE CASCADE | ON DELETE SET NULL]` doesn't make sense at all. You should probably study the manual regarding `CREATE TABLE` statements once more or more deeply.

Comment: It's oracle, my bad there. And what would the correct form be for the last line, if I may ask?

Comment: Depends on what you want -- setting the column to `NULL` or cascading the delete...

Answer (score 0):

Validating your code is much easier if it is formatted so that it is easily readable; so, first off, fix it so you can read it by separating the columns on to separate lines (which isn't done for the first and second columns) and by using indentation to assist with the readability.

Then you need an opening bracket after the table name and before the first column's definition.

Finally, you need to sort out the last line. Probably just removing the square brackets and their contents; but if you want to specify the `ON DELETE` action then pick one clause.

```sql
create table emp_copy (
  employee_id    NUMBER(6)
                 CONSTRAINT emp_employee_id PRIMARY KEY
, first_name     VARCHAR2(20)
, last_name      VARCHAR2(25)
                 CONSTRAINT emp_lname_nn NOT NULL
, email          VARCHAR2(25)
                 CONSTRAINT emp_mail NOT NULL
                 CONSTRAINT emp_mail_uk UNIQUE
, phone_number   VARCHAR2(20)
, hire_date      DATE
                 DEFAULT sysdate
                 CONSTRAINT emp_hire_date NOT NULL
, job_id         VARCHAR2(10)
                 CONSTRAINT emp_job NOT NULL
, salary         NUMBER(8,2)
                 CONSTRAINT emp_sal_ck CHECK (salary>0)
, commission_pct NUMBER(2,2)
, mgr_id         NUMBER(6)
                 CONSTRAINT emp_mgr_fk REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
, department_id  NUMBER(4)
                 CONSTRAINT empdept_fk REFERENCES dept (deptno)
);
```

Naming the constraints is good practice (quite a few people don't bother and it comes back to haunt them later during debugging so its good to see it being done); however, you might want to check through the names you've used and make sure the naming convention is consistently applied. If you are going to use `_nn`, `_ck`, `_fk`, `_uk` (why `uk`?) and `_pk` suffixes (which can be helpful to tell you the type of constraint violated at a glance) then use them everywhere.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dae5f20e28e511f9bc4c3eeb23721feb)*

Comment: Some of the inconsistencies in constraint naming could lie at the foot of EMP_**COPY**: there's probably an existing EMP in the same schema which has nabbed some obvious names. Or is that too much credit?